# Trying to print on thermal printer using print.js

Tags: reactjs, printing, thermal-printer, point-of-sale, printjs

Trying to print a pdf receipt, but it adds empty spaces on top and bottom.

```
const responseBlob = new Blob([pdfBlob], {
    type: 'application/pdf'
  });
  const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(responseBlob);
  setPreview(false);
  // printJS(fileURL);
  printJS({
    type: 'pdf',
    printable: fileURL,
    honorMarginPadding: true,
    style: '@page { size: 80mm 50mm }'

  });
```

But I am getting print like this.

[image]

PDF file

[image]

**Solution:**
Instead of PrintJS, use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

Comment: Hello, were you able to solve this issue?  @rohit-deshmukh

Comment: @negrotico19 Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve the issue
These adjustments should help in eliminating any unwanted spacing and ensuring that the content fits within a single page with the specified page size of 80mm
printJS({
printable: receiptRef.current,
type: 'html',
scanStyles: false,
style: `@page { size: 80mm 100%; margin: 0; } body { margin: 0; } /* Additional styles to ensure no unwanted spacing */ html, body, #root, #root > div { margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }`,
});